# print WPF visual using MVVM Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, reporting, prism

this question may be asked before but I could not find any suitable solution for my requirement.
I have a requirement that printing a report in WPF application, In WPF application I am using Prism Modular approach. I have written a User Control for the report and bind it with ViewModel.

On Print Command, I am getting View by using following code.

```
var view = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<SalesInvoiceReport>();
```

and passing this view to PrintDialog using following code.

```
if (pd.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    Size pageSize = new Size(pd.PrintableAreaWidth - 20, pd.PrintableAreaHeight - 20);

    pd.PrintVisual(view, "A Scaled Drawing");

    view.Background = null;

    view.LayoutTransform = null;
}
```

The PrintDialog prints the View, but its not showing any data on the report.
What I am doing wrong? As I guess the ViewModel is not working properly. 
The idea I got from the following code, as I am adding views in the application by this way.

```
var view = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Medicose.Navigation.View.NewOrder>();
IRegion region1 = this._regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainRegion];

region1.Add(view);
if (region1 != null)
{
    region1.Activate(view);
}
```

But here I don't want to add the view in region, I want it to directly print as report. Please correct me or give me idea if I am doing wrong.I am new In developing WPF PRISM app development.

Edit---

```
public partial class SalesInvoiceReport : UserControl
{
    public SalesInvoiceReport(Medicose.Navigation.ViewModel.Reports.SalesInvoiceReportViewModel model)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = model;
    }
}
```

ViewModel....

```
public sealed class SalesInvoiceReportViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    #region private members
    private EntityFContext context;

    private IProductsService productsservice;

    private static readonly int orderNumber;............
```

Comment: Please post how do you set this view's `DataContext` when you create it for printing. XAML? DI?

Comment: I see you're using a dependency injection in that view. Which IoC container are you using with Prism? MEF / Unity / other? Have you tried to set a breakpoint into your view's parameterized constructor to check whether it actually gets called?

Comment: I am using Prism Unity..and I have set breakpoints into Viewmodel constructor and UserControl's Constructor as well, both constructors are calling but the datacontext is not working , I think this view is not activating, How can this be activated without adding in any Region? is it possible or not (i am not sure) but as i think Region is necessary for activating any view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, it was my mistake that I could not imagine to happen with me, Actually the constructor of my ViewModel for report printing was called, but i was not calling the method to fill the report content. however I was confused with other problem that happens with me in this matter, that is getting an OrderId.
I have made a public static field to get the order number from NewOrderViewModel.
NewOrderViewModel has print Command. and I am setting the value of order Id by makeing a static field in ReportViewModel. I am doing this right or wrong? please correct me for best practices, I tried to use dependency property as well but i could not get the value at viewModel through using dependencyProperty.

B.R